# Dúvidas sobre Scroll javaScript

Tags: javascript

tudo bem?

Gostaria de saber como faço para capturar o scroll da página e aparecer a quantidade de scroll rolado no console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa! 
Se vc quer renderizar na pagina o valor do screen, vc pode criar uma função ativada pelo evento scroll... e inserir no HTML de um elemento da sua pagina o valor do screen. Por exemplo:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Valor do Scroll da pagina</h1>
    <p id="valorScroll">x</p>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Aplica esse style para vc conseguir visualizar o efeito:

```
body{
  height:200vh;
}

div{
  position:fixed;
}
```

Ai vc faz uma função:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    document.getElementById("valorScroll").innerHTML=window.window.scrollY
}
```

Pen do resultado: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQKjwr

Answer (score 0):

O `javascript` tem o objeto `window` que tem a propriedade `scrollY` onde mostra o quanto de scroll foi feito na pagina...

tente usar `console.log(window.scrollY)`

```css
div{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = scroll;

function scroll () {
  console.log(window.scrollY , 'aa')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Boa tarde Otávio blz, o código que você me passou realmente aparece o valor no console mas eu queria que a partir do momento que eu role o scroll no console apareça a quantidade em números, obrigado.

Comment: Oi editei a resposta vê se te ajuda...